# TextView isn't shown above the Button in more than API 21

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview

I want to show a TextView above the Button, but in API 21, Button above TextView.

[see image, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kltu7.jpg)

I try `android:elevation` but it make a shadow for Textview, it's not good.

I try `android:translationZ="100dip"` but, didn't work.

my xml Codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_food"
            android:text="@string/main_matrial1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@color/listview_matrial"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_material1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="material 1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/custom_listview_food"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are not satisfied ping the layout design in which way you want the screen. I will suggest you.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_listview_material1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="material 1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/custom_listview_food"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/custom_listview_food"
    android:text="main_matrial1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_listview_material1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, but with this code, just they are changed their position.I want button goes under TextView. please see the image